# boost::asio - the acceptor doesn't call the callback after the server is stopped and started again

Tags: c++, boost, server, boost-asio

I've created a simple wrapper for boost::asio library. My wrapper consists of 4 main classes: NetServer (server), NetClient (client), NetSession (client/server session) and Network (composition class of these three which also includes all callback methods).
The problem is that the first connection client/server works flawlessly, but when I then stop server, start it again and then try to connect the client, the server just doesn't recognize the client. It seems like the acceptor callback isn't called. And client does connect to server, because first - the connection goes without errors, second - when I close the server's program, the client receives the error message WSAECONNRESET.

I've created test program which emulates the procedure written above. It does following:

1. Starts the server
2. Starts the client
3. Client succesfully connects to server
4. Stops the server
5. Client receives the error and disconnects itself
6. Starts the server again
7. Client again succesfully connects to server
8. BUT SERVER DOESN'T CALL THE ACCEPTOR CALLBACK ANYMORE

It means that in point 3 the acceptor succesfully calls the callback function, but in point 7 the acceptor doesn't call the callback.

I think I do something wrong in stop()/start() method of the server, but I can't figure out what's exactly wrong.

The source of the NetServer class:

```
NetServer::NetServer(Network& netRef) : net{ netRef }
{
    acceptor = std::make_unique<boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor>(ioc);
}

NetServer::~NetServer(void)
{
    ioc.stop();
    if (threadStarted)
    {
        th.join();
        threadStarted = false;
    }
    if (active)
        stop();
}

int NetServer::start(void)
{
    assert(getAcceptHandler() != nullptr);
    assert(getHeaderHandler() != nullptr);
    assert(getDataHandler() != nullptr);
    assert(getErrorHandler() != nullptr);

    closeAll(); 

    try
    {

        ep = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), srvPort);
        acceptor->open(ep.protocol());
        acceptor->bind(ep);
        acceptor->listen();
        initAccept();
    }
    catch (system::system_error& e)
    {
        return e.code().value();
    }
    
    if (!threadStarted)
    {
        th = std::thread([this]()
            {
                ioc.run();
            });
        threadStarted = true;
    }

    active = true;
    return Network::NET_OK;
}

int NetServer::stop(void)
{
    ioc.post(boost::bind(&NetServer::_stop, this));
    return Network::NET_OK;
} 


void NetServer::_stop(void)
{
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    acceptor->close(ec);

    for (auto& s : sessions)
        closeSession(s.get(), false);

    active = false;
    

}

void NetServer::initAccept(void)
{
    sock = std::make_shared<asio::ip::tcp::socket>(ioc);
    
    acceptor->async_accept(*sock.get(), [this](const boost::system::error_code& error)
        {
            onAccept(error, sock);
        });
}

void NetServer::onAccept(const boost::system::error_code& ec, SocketSharedPtr sock)
{
    if (ec.value() == 0)
    {
        if (accHandler()) 
        {
            addSession(sock);
            initAccept();
        }
    }
    else
        getErrorHandler()(nullptr, ec);
}

SessionPtr NetServer::addSession(SocketSharedPtr sock)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtxSession);
    auto session = std::make_shared<NetSession>(sock, *this, true);
    sessions.insert(session);
    session->start();

    return session;
}

SessionPtr NetServer::findSession(const SessionPtr session)
{
    for (auto it = std::begin(sessions); it != std::end(sessions); it++)
        if (*it == session)
            return *it;
        
    return nullptr;
}

bool NetServer::closeSession(const void *session, bool erase /* = true */)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtxSession);

    for (auto it = std::begin(sessions); it != std::end(sessions); it++)
        if (it->get() == session)
        {
            try
            {
                it->get()->getSocket()->cancel();
                it->get()->getSocket()->shutdown(asio::socket_base::shutdown_send);
                it->get()->getSocket()->close();
                it->get()->getSocket().reset();
            }
            catch (system::system_error& e)
            {
                UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(e);
            }

            if (erase)
                sessions.erase(*it);
            return true;
            
        }
    return false;
}

void NetServer::closeAll(void)
{
    using namespace boost::placeholders;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mtxSession);
    std::for_each(sessions.begin(), sessions.end(), boost::bind(&NetSession::stop, _1));
    sessions.clear();
}

bool NetServer::write(const SessionPtr session, std::string msg)
{
    if (SessionPtr s = findSession(session); s)
    {
        s->addMessage(msg);
        if (s->canWrite()) 
            s->write();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the output from the server:

```
Enter 0 - server, 1 - client: 0
1. Server started
3. Client connected to server
Stopping server....
4. Server stopped
Net error, server, acceptor: ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED
Net error, server, ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED
Client session deleted
6. Server started again
(HERE SHOULD BE "8. Client again connected to server", but the server didn't recognize the reconnected client!)
```

And from the client:

```
Enter 0 - server, 1 - client: 1
2. Client started and connected to server
Net error, client: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
5. Client disconnected from server
Waiting 3 sec before reconnect...
Connecting to server...
7. Client started and connected to server
(WHEN I CLOSE THE SERVER WINDOW, I RECVEIVE HERE THE "Net error, client: WSAECONNRESET" MESSAGE - it means client was connected to server anyhow!)
```

If the code of NetClient, NetSession and Network is necessary, just let me know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you call reset after stop on io_context?

Comment: No. As you can see, I don't even stop the `ioc` in the `stop()` method. I stop it only in the destructor. So the object uses the same ioc in subsequent sessions. I did it so because I received the exception "`resource deadlock would occur`" when I tried to join the `ioc` thread in the `stop()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. There's a lot to unpack. There is quite a lot of code smell that reminds me of some books on Asio programming that turned out to be... not excellent in my previous experience.

I couldn't give any real advice without grokking your code, which requires me to review in-depth and add missing bits. So let me just provide you with my reviewed/fixed code first, then we'll talk about some of the details.

A few areas where you seemed to have trouble making up your mind:

1. whether to use a strand or to use mutex locking
2. whether to use async or sync (e.g. `closeSession` is completely synchronous and blokcing)
3. whether to use shared-pointers for lifetime or not: on the one hand you have `NetSesion` support shared_from_this, but on the other hand you are keeping them alive in a `sessions` collection.
4. whether to use smart pointers or raw pointers (sp.get() is a code smell)
5. whether to use void* pointers or forward declared structs for opaque implementation
6. whether to use exceptions or to use error codes. Specifically:

   ```
   return e.code().value();
   ```

   is a Very Bad Idea. Just return `error_code` already. Or just propagate the exception.
7. judging from the use, my best bet is that `sessions` is `std::set<SessionPtr>`. Then it's funny that you're doing linear searches. In fact, `findSession` could be:

   ```
   SessionPtr findSession(SessionPtr const& session) {
       std::lock_guard guard(mtxSessions);
       return sessions.contains(session)? session: nullptr;
   }
   ```

   In fact, given some natural invariants, it could just be

   ```
   auto findSession(SessionPtr s) { return std::move(s); }
   ```
8. Note as well, you had forgotten to lock the mutex in `findSession`
9. `closeSession` completely violates Law Of Demeter, 6*3 times over if you will. In my example I make it so `SessHandle` is a weak pointer to `NetSession` and you can just write:

   ```
   for (auto& handle : sessions)
       if (auto sess = handle.lock())
           sess->close();
   ```
10. Of course, `sess->close()` should not block
11. Also, it should **correctly synchronize** on the session e.g. using the sessions strand:

    ```
    void close() {
        return post(sock_.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
            error_code ec;
            if (!ec) sock_.cancel(ec);
            if (!ec) sock_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, ec);
            if (!ec) sock_.close(ec);
        });
    }
    ```

    If you insist, you can make it so the caller **can** still await the result and receive any exceptions:

    ```
    std::future<void> close() {
        return post(
            sock_.get_executor(),
            std::packaged_task<void()>{[this, self = shared_from_this()] {
                sock_.cancel();
                sock_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
                sock_.close();
            }});
    }
    ```

    Honestly, that seems overkill since you never look at the return value anyways.
12. In general, I recommend leaving `socket::close()` to the destructor. It avoids a specific class of race-conditions on socket handles.
13. Don't use boolean flags (`isThreadActive` is better replaced with `th.joinable()`)
14. apparently you had `NetSession::stop` which I imagine did largely the same as `closeSession` but in the right place? I replaced it with the new `NetSession::close`
15. subtly when `accHandler` returned false, you would exit the accept loop alltogether. I doubt that was on purpose
16. try to minimize time under locks:

    ```
    std::future<void> close() {
        return post(
            sock_.get_executor(),
            std::packaged_task<void()>{[this, self = shared_from_this()] {
                sock_.cancel();
                sock_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send);
                sock_.close();
            }});
    }
    ```

    I will show you how to do without the lock entirely instead.

**[Demo Listing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d2890690acea3b6)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <set>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::placeholders;
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;

static inline std::ostream debug(std::cerr.rdbuf());

struct Network {
    static constexpr error_code NET_OK{};
};

struct NetSession; // opaque forward reference
struct NetServer;
using SessHandle = std::weak_ptr<NetSession>; // opaque handle
using Sessions   = std::set<SessHandle, std::owner_less<>>;

struct NetSession : std::enable_shared_from_this<NetSession> {
    NetSession(tcp::socket&& s, NetServer& srv, bool)
        : sock_(std::move(s))
        , srv_(srv) {
        debug << "New session from " << getPeer() << std::endl;
    }

    void start() {
        post(sock_.get_executor(),
             std::bind(&NetSession::do_read, shared_from_this()));
    }

    tcp::endpoint getPeer() const { return peer_; }

    void close() {
        return post(sock_.get_executor(), [this, self = shared_from_this()] {
            debug << "Closing " << getPeer() << std::endl;
            error_code ec;
            if (!ec) sock_.cancel(ec);
            if (!ec) sock_.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, ec);
            // if (!ec) sock_.close(ec);
        });
    }

    void addMessage(std::string msg) {
        post(sock_.get_executor(),
             [this, msg = std::move(msg), self = shared_from_this()] {
                 outgoing_.push_back(std::move(msg));
                 if (canWrite())
                     write_loop();
             });
    }

  private:
    // assumed on (logical) strand
    bool canWrite() const { // FIXME misnomer: shouldStartWriteLoop()?
        return outgoing_.size() == 1;
    }

    void write_loop() {
        if (outgoing_.empty())
            return;

        async_write(sock_, asio::buffer(outgoing_.front()),
                    [this, self = shared_from_this()](error_code ec, size_t) {
                        if (!ec) {
                            outgoing_.pop_front();
                            write_loop();
                        }
                    });
    }

    void do_read() {
        incoming_.clear();
        async_read_until(
            sock_, asio::dynamic_buffer(incoming_), "\n",
            std::bind(&NetSession::on_read, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
    }

    void on_read(error_code ec, size_t);

    tcp::socket   sock_;
    tcp::endpoint peer_ = sock_.remote_endpoint();
    NetServer&    srv_;

    std::string             incoming_;
    std::deque<std::string> outgoing_;
};

using SessionPtr      = std::shared_ptr<NetSession>;
using SocketSharedPtr = std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>;

struct NetServer {
    NetServer(Network& netRef) : net{netRef} {}

    ~NetServer()
    {
        if (acceptor.is_open())
            acceptor.cancel(); // TODO seems pretty redundant
        stop();
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }

    std::function<bool()>                                    accHandler;
    std::function<void(SocketSharedPtr, error_code)>         errHandler;
    // TODO headerHandler
    std::function<void(SessionPtr, error_code, std::string)> dataHandler;

    error_code start() {
        assert(accHandler);
        assert(errHandler);
        assert(dataHandler);

        closeAll(sessions);

        error_code ec;
        if (!ec) acceptor.open(tcp::v4(), ec);
        if (!ec) acceptor.bind({{}, srvPort}, ec);
        if (!ec) acceptor.listen(tcp::socket::max_listen_connections, ec);
        if (!ec) {
            do_accept();

            if (!th.joinable()) {
                th = std::thread([this] { ioc.run(); }); // TODO exceptions!
            }
        }

        if (ec && acceptor.is_open())
            acceptor.close();

        return ec;
    }

    void stop() { //
        post(ioc, std::bind(&NetServer::do_stop, this));
    }

    void closeSession(SessHandle handle, bool erase = true) {
        post(acceptor.get_executor(), [=, this] {
            if (auto s = handle.lock()) {
                s->close();
            }

            if (erase) {
                sessions.erase(handle);
            }
        });
    }

    void closeAll() {
        post(acceptor.get_executor(), [this] {
            closeAll(sessions);
            sessions.clear();
        });
    }

    // TODO FIXME is the return value worth it?
    bool write(SessionPtr const& session, std::string msg) {
        return post(acceptor.get_executor(),
                    std::packaged_task<bool()>{std::bind(
                        &NetServer::do_write, this, session, std::move(msg))})
            .get();
    }

    // compare
    void writeAll(std::string msg) {
        post(acceptor.get_executor(),
             std::bind(&NetServer::do_write_all, this, std::move(msg)));
    }

  private:
    Network& net;

    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::acceptor    acceptor{ioc}; // active -> acceptor.is_open()
    std::thread      th;            // threadActive -> th.joinable()
    Sessions         sessions;
    std::uint16_t    srvPort = 8989;

    // std::mutex mtxSessions; // note naming; also replaced by logical strand

    // assumed on acceptor logical strand
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor.async_accept(
            make_strand(ioc), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket sock) {
                if (ec.failed()) {
                    return errHandler(nullptr, ec);
                }

                if (accHandler()) {
                    auto s = std::make_shared<NetSession>(std::move(sock),
                                                          *this, true);
                    sessions.insert(s);
                    s->start();
                }
                do_accept();
            });
    }

    SessionPtr do_findSession(SessionPtr const& session) {
        return sessions.contains(session) ? session : nullptr;
    }

    bool do_write(SessionPtr session, std::string msg) {
        if (auto s = do_findSession(session)) {
            s->addMessage(std::move(msg));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void do_write_all(std::string msg) {
        for(auto& handle : sessions)
            if (auto sess = handle.lock())
                do_write(sess, msg);
    }

    static void closeAll(Sessions const& sessions) {
        for (auto& handle : sessions)
            if (auto sess = handle.lock())
                sess->close();
    }

    void do_stop()
    {
        if (acceptor.is_open()) {
            error_code ec;
            acceptor.close(ec); // TODO error handling?
        }

        closeAll(sessions); // TODO FIXME why not clear sessions?
    }
};

// Implementation must be after NetServer definition:
void NetSession::on_read(error_code ec, size_t) {
    if (srv_.dataHandler)
        srv_.dataHandler(shared_from_this(), ec, std::move(incoming_));

    if (!ec)
        do_read();
}

int main() {
    Network net;

    NetServer srv{net};
    srv.accHandler = [] { return true; };
    srv.errHandler = [](SocketSharedPtr, error_code ec) {
        debug << "errHandler: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
    };
    srv.dataHandler = [](SessionPtr sess, error_code ec, std::string msg) {
        debug << "dataHandler: " << sess->getPeer() << " " << ec.message()
              << " " << std::quoted(msg) << std::endl;
    };

    srv.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(10s);
    std::cout << "Shutdown started" << std::endl;

    srv.writeAll("We're going to shutdown, take care!\n");

    srv.stop();
}
```

Live Demo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for valuable remarks on my code. I realize that the code is raw and not optimized. I just stuck with this acceptor problem.
I copied your code and compiled in my Visual Studio. Unfortunately, the `sessions.contains` doesn't work in Visual Studio (seems `set` doesn't have the `contains` method).
The second problem is more interesting: I tested your program and emulated stop and start of the server. After second start the server didn't recognize the client, so it's the same problem like in my code. I tested it with my network client and with the windows' telnet.

Comment: `set::contains` is c++20. So, just use `set::count` or so

Comment: Re _"I tested your program and emulated stop"_. Well you're so close now... You can edit the Coliru example to show what you did. Then I can also see it

Comment: I did only small changes in `main` function. Here is the link: [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e28445ca35db072d)

Comment: Ah. You need to keep the thread running e.g. with a work-guard http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ec23604dc1c2783. Or  you can simplify all that using `asio::thread_pool` or so.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! The funniest thing is that I previously did use work-guard in NetServer, but removed it because I read somewhere that the asynchronous server always does async_accept, so it always has at least one task scheduled. So it seems it was not true. Thanks again for finding the bug and for bunch of valuable suggestions!

Comment: It was true! Until you stopped it (`acceptor.cancel()` and `acceptor.close()` have a tendency to break that :))

Comment: OK, everything clear! The description I read lacked information that `acceptor->close()` changes the whole situation!